# kernel issue while running custom image

Tags: google-compute-engine

I followed the proper documentation regarding specifying kernel in the command line while bundling the GCE image.

I specified the following:

```
--preferred_kernel=projects/google/global/kernels/gce-v20130515
```

The image bundle process works out ok and I get no errors. But when I run the add instance command, I get the following error:

```
$ gcutil addinstance --image=hareem --kernel=gce-v20130515 mynewinstance --project=my-project
INVALID_FIELD_VALUE: Invalid value for field 'resource.kernels': 'projects/hlabsgce/global/kernels/gce-v20130515'. Resource was not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the full name for the Kernel here, it looks like gcutil is looking for the Google kernel in your private project:

```
'projects/hlabsgce/global/kernels/gce-v20130515'
```

instead of

```
'projects/google/global/kernels/gce-v20130515'
```

Try:

```
gcutil addinstance --image=hareem --kernel=projects/google/global/kernels/gce-v20130515 mynewinstance --project=my-project
```

gcutil should use the prefered kernel by default though, so you might not even need to supply that parameter.